# Run time type identification

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, enums, polymorphism

I want to check type at run time, but I don't want to use the `instanceOf()` or `getClass()` methods in Java.

Thus I did the following:

I created an enum

```
public enum CarType{
            SEDAN,
            SUV
        }
```

I created an interface

```
public interface Car{

public CarType getCarType();
}
```

Then I wrote two classes which implement `Car`.

```
public class Sedan implements Car{
   public CarType getCarType(){
     return CarType.SEDAN
  }
}
```

Now another class is

```
public class Suv implements Car{
       public CarType getCarType(){
         return CarType.Suv
      }
}
```

Then I use these Classes in some other class's method as

```
class CarUI{

    public void updateTheUIConsideringCarType(CarType type) {
            switch(type){
            case SUV:
               //UI to update when car type is SUV
            case SEDAN:
               //UI to update when car type is SEDAN
                break;
            default: 
              break;
          }
        }
}
```

I want to ask, if I use this way is it a good way or is it the same as using `instanceOf()`, I want to stick to OOP.

Also if there is a better way please let me know.

Comment: It's slightly better than relying on inheritance (inheritance is open-ended, while an enum has a fixed number of elements) but still not ideal. The exact solution will depend on many factors though.

Comment: The best way could be having the `updateTheUI` method declared in `Car` interface and implemented separately in each class. I myself would consider an enum `switch` cleaner than `instanceof`, but neither one is very good. One possible way would be making `CarUI` an interface and implementing it for each type.

Comment: @Bubletan I disagree. You are suggesting to directly couple the model with UI related activities. But such things should be independent. So your suggestion is **one** way of resolving, but nothing makes it the "best way".

Comment: @Bubletan That's one way of dealing with it. You can also create a `CarUIUpdater` interface and pass a separate implementation to each car, to avoid the car code being mixed with UI updating code. There are lots of other options but the problem isn't detailed enough to choose.

Comment: @Jägermeister Yeah, after thinking again, it might get a bit messy if UI related things would be inside `Car`. But still splitting it to multiple classes allows keeping it more organized.

Comment: Is there a reason to have the two distinct classes `Suv` and `Sedan`? As currently written, they don’t differ in behavior but just in the value of a single property.

Comment: @Holger this situation is common in day today programming, here i have give an example. The other use case can also fits in this. The concept i want to understand is, ideally if there is a need to know what type of an object is, then there is some flaw in the design. Thus I wanted to know if an object has some property that distinguishes it from other object then is that property equivalent to using instanceOf or thats the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly a good idea to use this mechanism - it saves many ours of work later.

There is even one further step you can take (if appropriate to your code) - make the `enum` do the UI painting.

```
public interface CanDraw {

    public void draw();
}

public enum CarType implements CanDraw {

    SEDAN {

                @Override
                public void draw() {
                    // Do your UI drawing here.
                }

            },
    SUV {

                @Override
                public void draw() {
                    // Do your UI drawing here.
                }

            };
}

public void updateTheUIConsideringCarType(CarType type) {
    type.draw();
}
```

As noted in the comments this can sometimes lead to your UI code leaking into your model code. It is generally better to avoid this by returning functionality from your UI - something like this:

```
public interface CanDraw {

    public void draw();
}

// In your UI.
public enum CarDrawingPolicy implements CanDraw {

    SMALL {

                @Override
                public void draw() {
                    // Do your UI drawing here.
                }

            },
    BIG {

                @Override
                public void draw() {
                    // Do your UI drawing here.
                }

            };
}

public interface HasDrawingPolicy {

    public CarDrawingPolicy getDrawingPolicy();
}

// In your Model
public enum CarType implements HasDrawingPolicy {

    SEDAN {

                @Override
                public CarDrawingPolicy getDrawingPolicy() {
                    return CarDrawingPolicy.SMALL;
                }

            },
    SUV {

                @Override
                public CarDrawingPolicy getDrawingPolicy() {
                    return CarDrawingPolicy.BIG;
                }

            };
}

public void updateTheUIConsideringCarType(CarType type) {
    type.getDrawingPolicy().draw();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that making the `enum` do the painting is a good idea. It looks like you're conflating the model with the view code. If you're writing an MVC application you should keep the concerns of model and view separate.

Comment: @Jesper In the case of UI it's arguable, but in principle it's nothing wrong with a strategy enum. If you called the enum `CarDrawingPolicy` instead of `CarType`, it would be a textbook solution.

Comment: @Jesper - You are correct - it is not always appropriate to make the `enum` do too much, however, making the `enum` know **how** to do it (perhaps by injection) can be a very effective half-way solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this approach is that any new implementation of Car requires changes to multiple files that all must remain in sync with one another. In other words, these classes are tightly coupled.
Whatever logic is in the updateTheUIConsideringCarType should instead be encapsulated in each of the car implementations.

So you car interface might be something like:

```
public interface Car{
    public Object getUiStuff();
}
```

So then your updateTheUIConsideringCarType would be defined as:

```
public void updateTheUIConsideringCarType(Car car) {
    car.getUiStuff();
}
```

Comment: I disagree, this is adding view concerns into model. For example, if Car is used in multiple layers of the application, UI classes may not even be present on classpath in the middle or persistence layers.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic I didn't want to make any assumptions about the nature of the Car objects. If they are model objects then it would be simple enough to add Car view objects and the solution remains the same.